# Syntax Error in MySQL - Same syntax worked in earlier table

Tags: mysql, syntax, foreign-keys

I'm working on building a small database and am running into a syntax error on these two lines in my last table.

They're foreign keys and those lines didn't produce any errors in the tables where they originally appeared.

```
INVOICE_ID     INTEGER    NOT NULL   AUTO_INCREMENT   UNIQUE,
DONUT_ID     VARCHAR(10)    NOT NULL   UNIQUE,
```

These two lines are the PK and FK in the table, and I think this is where I'm running into the problem because I used the same syntax as I did in earlier tables that aren't generating any errors.

Here is the full code for four tables:

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER (
CUST_ID      INT    NOT NULL     AUTO_INCREMENT     UNIQUE,
CUST_LNAME      VARCHAR(25)    NOT NULL,
CUST_FNAME      VARCHAR(25)    NOT NULL,
CUST_INITIAL   CHAR(1),
CUST_STREET_NO   VARCHAR(6),
CUST_STREET_NAME     VARCHAR(25),
CUST_APT_NO     VARCHAR(10),
CUST_CITY     VARCHAR(25),
CUST_STATE     CHAR(2),
CUST_ZIP_CODE     CHAR(5),
CUST_HOME_AC     CHAR(3),
CUST_HOME_PHONE     CHAR(8),
PRIMARY KEY (CUST_ID)
)ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE INVOICE (
INVOICE_ID     INTEGER    NOT NULL   AUTO_INCREMENT   UNIQUE,
CUST_ID      INTEGER    NOT NULL,
INV_DATE   DATE    NOT NULL,
SPECIAL_HANDLING   VARCHAR(35),
PRIMARY KEY (INVOICE_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (CUST_ID) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CUST_ID) ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE PRODUCT (
DONUT_ID     VARCHAR(10)    NOT NULL   UNIQUE,
DONUT_NAME      VARCHAR(25)    NOT NULL,
DONUT_DESC   VARCHAR(35)    NOT NULL,
DONUT_PRICE   DECIMAL(13,2)   NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (DONUT_ID)
)ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE INVOICE LINE ITEM (
INVOICE_ID     INTEGER    NOT NULL   AUTO_INCREMENT   UNIQUE,
DONUT_ID     VARCHAR(10)    NOT NULL   UNIQUE,
DONUT_QTY     INTEGER   NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (INVOICE_ID, DONUT_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (INVOICE_ID) REFERENCES INVOICE(INVOICE_ID) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (DONUT_ID) REFERENCES PRODUCT(DONUT_ID) ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fourth `CREATE TABLE` statement will fail because of the spaces in the table name:

```
CREATE TABLE INVOICE LINE ITEM ...
```

You should use a different name, without spaces. For example you could replace the spaces with underscores and use snake-case:

```
CREATE TABLE INVOICE_LINE_ITEM ...
```

Comment: It's always the easiest things, isn't it? Can't believe I missed that.....